# Decreasing the distance between bent propagator and corresponding momentum

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-feynman

I would like to know is it possible to adjust the distance between bent propagator and corresponding bent momentum arrow, when using tikz-feynman package? Actually, I would like to decrease this distance. The mentioned arrow is in-between the points: z ans z_2. Also, could I displace the momentum arrow, so that it's not centered over the propagator?  My code is:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a1)[scale=0.7][blob,label=180:\(J\), label=20:\(z_0\)] {};
\vertex(a2)[right=0.9cm of a1,dot, label=90:\(z_{}\)]{} ;
\vertex(a3)[right=0.7cm of a2, dot, label=90:\(z_1\)]{} ;
\vertex(a4)[below right=0.7cm and 2.1cm of a2, dot, label=90:\(z_2\)]{} ;
\vertex[right=3.9cm of a3](a5){\(p{,}d\)};
\vertex(a6)[below=1.5cm of a3, crossed dot,label=270:\(\vec{\bf{q_1}} {,}a_1\)]{};
\vertex(a7)[below=0.8cm of a4, crossed dot,label=270:\(\vec{\bf{q_2}} {,}a_2\)]{};
\vertex(a8)[right=2.5cm of a4]{\(k{,}c\)};

  \diagram* {
(a1) -- [gluon, momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.2, arrow distance=0.6] }] (a2) -- [gluon,  momentum={[arrow shorten=0.2, arrow distance=0.6] }] (a3)-- [gluon,  momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.38, arrow distance=0.25] }] (a5),
(a2) -- [gluon, /tikz/out=-45 ,/tikz/in=185, momentum={[arrow shorten=0.3]} ] (a4)--[gluon, momentum= {[arrow shorten=0.3, arrow distance=0.25]}](a8) ,

(a6) -- [gluon,  momentum={[arrow shorten=0.3, arrow distance=0.4]}](a3) ,
(a7) -- [gluon,  momentum={[arrow shorten=0.2, arrow distance=0.55]}](a4) ,
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here is the figure:
[image]

Comment: Is using `momentum={[shift={(6.6pt,-2.5pt)},arrow shorten=0.3,]}` achieving the effect you want?

Comment: Bold face *and* a vector arrow seems excessive.  Better use only `\mathbf{q}_2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another nice diagram using [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman))!

So regarding your main question: yes it is possible to adjust the distance between the momentum arrow and the corresponding propagator using

```
arrow distance=<num>
```

Though the effect of a particular number might change depending on whether it is a bent propagator or not.

At the moment, there is no support for momentum arrows which are not half-way along the corresponding line.  I might add this in the future if there's a demand for it, but we'll see.

Lastly in the following example, I have kept the exact same topology, but made untangled it and made it more symmetric which should make it easier for the reader.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex[scale=0.7, blob, label=180:\(J\), label=20:\(z_0\)] (a1) {};
    \vertex[right=1cm of a1,dot, label=0:\(z\)] (a2) {} ;
    \vertex[below right=0.7cm and 2cm of a2, dot, label=90:\(z_1\)] (a3) {};
    \vertex[above right=0.7cm and 2cm of a2, dot, label=-90:\(z_2\)] (a4) {};
    \vertex[right=2.5cm of a3] (a5) {\(p,d\)};
    \vertex[right=2.5cm of a4] (a8) {\(k,c\)};
    \vertex(a6)[below=1cm of a3, crossed dot, label=-90:{\(\vec{\bf{q_1}},a_1\)}]{};
    \vertex(a7)[above=1cm of a4, crossed dot, label=90:{\(\vec{\bf{q_2}},a_2\)}]{};

    \diagram* {
      (a1) -- [gluon, momentum'={}] (a2),
      (a2) -- [gluon, out=-60, in=180, momentum'={[arrow shorten=0.3, arrow distance=15]}] (a3)
           -- [gluon, momentum'={}] (a5),
      (a2) -- [gluon, out=60, in=180, momentum={[arrow shorten=0.3, arrow distance=15]}] (a4)
           -- [gluon, momentum={}] (a8),
      (a6) -- [gluon, momentum={}] (a3),
      (a7) -- [gluon, momentum'={}] (a4),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]